# Excel how to Copy and insert the first row into all other sheets without overwriting data

Tags: vba, excel

As the title I tried this one, but it overwrites existing data, I am looking for something that
add the header row in all sheets moving the data down. I have got 50 sheets that's why I am asking :-)

```
Sub CopyToAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("1:1")
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is `FillAcrossSheets` a member of the Worksheet object or a Class module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert a line in each sheet before filling the headers:

```
Sub CopyToAllSheets()

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In Sheets
        sheet.Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next sheet

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("1:1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I will be assuming that your header will be coming from another sheet. Recording a macro gives me:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Cleaning it up gives:

```
Sub InsertOnTop()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1:1").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Applying it safely across all sheets except the source sheet:

```
Sub InsertOnTopOfEachSheet()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, Source As Worksheet
    Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify to suit.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> Source.Name Then
            Source.Rows("1:1").Copy
            WS.Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next WS
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to loop through each sheet and insert a blank row, or just use the range.insert method on each sheet.  Perhaps something like:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyToAllSheets()
  Dim WS As Worksheet
For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not WS.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Rows(1)) > 0 Then _
            WS.Rows(1).Insert
    End If
Next WS

Worksheets.FillAcrossSheets Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), xlFillWithAll
End Sub
```